# How to make mutation which is inversion of one of the solution's genes when solutions are bit arrays

Tags: python, pygad

That's what I have so far. As I see from the output, my parameters are not enough to constraint mutation to my needs. Sometimes no one gene is changed, sometimes more than one.

```
import pygad
import numpy as np


def divider(ga_instance):
    return np.max(np.sum(ga_instance.population, axis=1))


def on_start(ga_instance):
    print("on_start()")
    print(f'Начальная популяция:\n {ga_instance.population}')


def fitness_function(ga_instance, solution, _):
    return np.sum(solution) / divider(ga_instance)


def on_fitness(ga_instance, population_fitness):
    print(f'\non_fitness()')
    print(f'Делитель: {divider(ga_instance)}')
    for idx, (instance, fitness) in enumerate(zip(ga_instance.population, ga_instance.last_generation_fitness)):
        print(f'{idx}. {instance}: {fitness}')


def on_parents(ga_instance, selected_parents):
    print("\non_parents()")
    print(f'Выбранные индексы родителей: {ga_instance.last_generation_parents_indices}')
    print(f'Выбранные родители:\n {ga_instance.last_generation_parents}')


def on_crossover(ga_instance, offspring_crossover):
    print("\non_crossover()")
    print(f'Результат кроссинговера:\n {ga_instance.last_generation_offspring_crossover}')


def on_mutation(ga_instance, offspring_mutation):
    print("\non_mutation()")
    print(f'Результат мутации:\n {ga_instance.last_generation_offspring_mutation}')


def on_generation(ga_instance):
    print(f"\non_generation()")
    print("Выведенное поколение:\n ", ga_instance.population)
    sol = ga_instance.best_solution()
    print(f"Лучшее решение: {sol[0]} : {sol[1]}")


ga_instance = pygad.GA(
    num_generations=1,
    num_parents_mating=2,
    fitness_func=fitness_function,
    gene_type=int,
    init_range_low=0,
    init_range_high=2,
    sol_per_pop=10,
    num_genes=8,
    crossover_type='single_point',
    parent_selection_type="rws",
    mutation_type="inversion",
    mutation_num_genes=1,
    on_start=on_start,
    on_fitness=on_fitness,
    on_parents=on_parents,
    on_crossover=on_crossover,
    on_mutation=on_mutation,
    on_generation=on_generation,
)

ga_instance.run()
```

More details for stackoverflow algorithm: sdfgdsfdddddddddddfffffffffadsgadfgdafgdasgadsgdsagdsagdsagadsgdsagdsagdsag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inversion mutation inverts the order of subset of the genes. It does not invert the value of the genes from 0 to 1. That is if you have a chromosome like **abcd**, then inversion mutation inverts the genes to be **dcba**.

To apply a mutation operator that flips the genes from 0 to 1 and from 1 to 0, use this code. It creates a new function `flip_mutation()` to flip the bits.

```py
import pygad
import numpy as np


def divider(ga_instance):
    return np.max(np.sum(ga_instance.population, axis=1))


def on_start(ga_instance):
    print("on_start()")
    print(f'Начальная популяция:\n {ga_instance.population}')


def fitness_function(ga_instance, solution, _):
    return np.sum(solution) / divider(ga_instance)


def on_fitness(ga_instance, population_fitness):
    print(f'\non_fitness()')
    print(f'Делитель: {divider(ga_instance)}')
    for idx, (instance, fitness) in enumerate(zip(ga_instance.population, ga_instance.last_generation_fitness)):
        print(f'{idx}. {instance}: {fitness}')


def on_parents(ga_instance, selected_parents):
    print("\non_parents()")
    print(f'Выбранные индексы родителей: {ga_instance.last_generation_parents_indices}')
    print(f'Выбранные родители:\n {ga_instance.last_generation_parents}')


def on_crossover(ga_instance, offspring_crossover):
    print("\non_crossover()")
    print(f'Результат кроссинговера:\n {ga_instance.last_generation_offspring_crossover}')


def on_mutation(ga_instance, offspring_mutation):
    print("\non_mutation()")
    print(f'Результат мутации:\n {ga_instance.last_generation_offspring_mutation}')


def on_generation(ga_instance):
    print(f"\non_generation()")
    print("Выведенное поколение:\n ", ga_instance.population)
    sol = ga_instance.best_solution()
    print(f"Лучшее решение: {sol[0]} : {sol[1]}")


def flip_mutation(offspring, ga_instance):
    for idx in range(offspring.shape[0]):
        mutation_gene1 = np.random.randint(low=0, high=np.ceil(offspring.shape[1]/2 + 1), size=1)[0]
        if offspring[idx, mutation_gene1] == 1:
            offspring[idx, mutation_gene1] = 0
        else:
            offspring[idx, mutation_gene1] = 1

    return offspring

ga_instance = pygad.GA(
    num_generations=1,
    num_parents_mating=2,
    fitness_func=fitness_function,
    gene_type=int,
    init_range_low=0,
    init_range_high=2,
    sol_per_pop=10,
    num_genes=8,
    crossover_type='single_point',
    parent_selection_type="rws",
    mutation_type=flip_mutation,
    mutation_num_genes=1,
    on_start=on_start,
    on_fitness=on_fitness,
    on_parents=on_parents,
    on_crossover=on_crossover,
    on_mutation=on_mutation,
    on_generation=on_generation,
)

ga_instance.run()
```